# How to see the content of a view in the main view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When I press the button named calendar I am directed to the controller where it is  called the main view which contains two DatePickers. After I select two dates and click on the submit button , I am directed in the controller in the method called "Plotting" that would open  a new  view that display a chart .My question is , can i display the chart view to be seen under the main view with the two DatePickers   because if i want to select other dates to not have to press the back button?

Here is my code from the controller which leads me to the main  view :

```
 public ActionResult Calendar()
         {
             ChartDate objdatemodel = new ChartDate();
             return View("Calendar",objdatemodel);
         }
```

Here is the code for the main view named Calendar

```
@model Plotting.Models.ChartDate
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "jQuery UI Datepicker Calender Control In Asp.Net Mvc Application";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<h2>
    Datepicker Calender
</h2>

<div id="yourviewDiv"></div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Plotting", "Greenhouse"))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Start Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, new { @id = "txtdatepicker1", @style = "width:200px;" })
                </p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    End Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, new { @id = "txtdatepicker2", @style = "width:200px;" })
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />   
}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#txtdatepicker1").datepicker();
    });
    $(function () {
        $("#txtdatepicker2").datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Here is the code from the controller for the view plotting:

```
     public ActionResult Plotting(ChartDate objdatemodel)
     {
         ChartDate cDate = new ChartDate();
         cDate.DateData = new DateChart();
         cDate.DateTitle = "Day";
         cDate.HumidityTitle1 = "Senzor 1";
         cDate.HumidityTitlle2 = "Senzor 2";

         List<Greenhouse> greenhouse = dal.FindDatesByInterval(objdatemodel.StartDate , objdatemodel.EndDate);
         String day = "";
         String humidity1 = "";
         String humidity2 = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < greenhouse.Count - 1; i++)
         {
             day += greenhouse[i].DateTime.Day + ",";
             humidity1 += greenhouse[i].Humidity1 + ",";
             humidity2 += greenhouse[i].Humidity2 + ",";

         }
         day += greenhouse[greenhouse.Count - 1].DateTime.Day;
         humidity1 += greenhouse[greenhouse.Count - 1].Humidity1;
         humidity2 += greenhouse[greenhouse.Count - 1].Humidity2;

         DateChart obj = new DateChart();
         /*Get the data from databse and prepare the chart record data in string form.*/
         obj.Date = day;
         obj.Humidity1 = humidity1;
         obj.Humidity2 = humidity2;
         cDate.DateData = obj;

         return View("Plotting",cDate);
     }
```

And here is the code for the Plotting view  :

```
@model Plotting.Models.ChartDate
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "How To Create Dynamic Google Column Chart In an Asp.Net MVC Application Using C# ";
}

<fieldset>
    <legend><strong>Greenhouse</strong></legend>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            // Create and populate the data table.
            var days = [@Model.DateData.Date];
            var humidities1 = [@Model.DateData.Humidity1];
            var humidities2 = [@Model.DateData.Humidity2];
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', '@Model.DateTitle');
            data.addColumn('number', '@Model.HumidityTitle1');
            data.addColumn('number', '@Model.HumidityTitlle2');
            for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([days[i].toString(), humidities1[i], humidities2[i]]);
            }
            var options = {
                title: 'Humidities Values',
                hAxis: { title: '@Model.DateTitle', titleTextStyle: { color: 'black' } }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }

    </script>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: auto; height: auto;">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Currently the code works , but if I want to put another chart I have to press the back button . You can put the two sites view the same view ? Thank you .

Comment: I think if someone were to give you the full answer, then you won't really get a full understanding of what is really happening.  You need to learn a little about Ajax and Partial Views, give it a shot, and come back with specific problems you have getting it to work.  To get you started though. https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/revisiting-partial-view-rendering-in-asp.net-mvc/

Comment: To answer your last question though.  No you don't want 2 Views in the same View.  Especially if they both use a layout page.  But you can put as many Partial Views in the same View as you want.  In your case you really only need one Partial View for the `Plotting` action to return.